# C: check file size

Tags: c, unix

I get the "Error: could not check file size". Any idea why?

```
  // Generate Content-Length                                                                                                       
  int file_size;
  int fd;
  char clenbuf[BUFLEN];
  struct stat fs;
  fd = open(filename, "r");
  if (fstat(fd, &fs) == -1) {
    printf("Error: could not check file size\n");
    return;
  }
  file_size = fs.st_size;
  sprintf(clenbuf, "Content-Length: %d", file_size);
```

Comment: You forgot to check whether the call to `open` was successful or not. Also you're getting confused between `fopen` and `open`. Try turning on compiler warnings too.

Comment: Did you think about checking the result of your `fopen()` call before just going ahead and using it? It doesn't just magically always manage to open everything you pass it in `filename`.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
fd = open(filename, "r");
if (NULL == fd) {
    printf("Could not open the file\n");
    exit(0);
}
if (fstat(fd, &fs) == -1) {
    printf("Error: could not check file size\n");
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following include was missing:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
```

Comment: That would've resulted in a compile-time error.  However, the Q indicates that the program ran, just not as expected.  (I won't down-vote, out of respect for the name Chuck Finley)

Comment: After I included fcntl.h everything worked just fine. I compiled with -W -Wall and had no warnings :)